# excel Sequence formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sequence

is it possible for the Sequence Formula to use a relative path as a [step]

I have a formula like this

```
=SEQUENCE($B$12*12,1,WORKDAY(EOMONTH(I27,1)+1,-1,HolidayList),$V20)
```

where I have the V column like below:

```
V20=1
V21=2
V22=3
```

However, the sequence will only get V20, but it does not refer to the relative cell, it will add 1 every time instead of adding 1 for the first record, and 2 for the second record.

Comment: Could you show us some sample data and the expected output?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Step is the gap between the previous and the next number of the sequence.